# Toggle div jQuery from <li> click

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, addclass

I'm trying to add the class "open-height" to a div and keep the class when I click in between the list items. Then remove the class when you click the same list item.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tonhaoln/sb2gt0fy/1/)**

```
$('#navlist a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the link from being followed
    $('#navlist a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $('.single-course-wrapp').toggleClass('open-height');
    } else {
      $('.single-course-wrapp').addClass('open-height');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb2gt0fy/3/)**.

You could achieve that using `data-*` attributes, by storing the id of li on `data-opened-by` attribute in the div then make condition to remove the class from it just when the clicked item has the same id stored on data attribute :

```js
$('#navlist a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the link from being followed
    
    $('#navlist a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    
    if($('.single-course-wrapp').hasClass('open-height')){
      var opener_id = $('.single-course-wrapp').data('opened-by');
       
        if($(this).parent().attr('id')==opener_id){
          $('.single-course-wrapp').removeClass('open-height');
        }
    }else{
        $('.single-course-wrapp').addClass('open-height');
        $('.single-course-wrapp').data('opened-by', $(this).parent().attr('id'));
    }
});
```

```css
.nav { color: green; }
.selected { color: red; }
.open-height{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:#000;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="home"><a class="nav" href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a class="nav" href="about-us">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="service"><a class="nav" href="about-us">Service</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a class="nav" href="about-us">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="single-course-wrapp">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zakaria! I appreciate your answer. 
Only thing is, if I 1st click on Home, 2nd click About and 3rd click About again, it should then close the box.
Is it possible?